# facebook cakephp plugin issues

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using the following:

cakephp 1.3

CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin 3.1.1 (branch cakephp 1.3)(webtechnick)

php 5.3.x

My problem is on line 146 of the following:

```
https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/blob/cakephp1.3/controllers/components/connect.php
```

I have manually set createUser to false as both an argument to the component, and by altering the default value in the component itself (set line 50 to false). Yet if I do this on line 147:

```
print "authUser: ".empty($this->authUser)." createUser: ".$this->createUser;
```

i get `"authUser: 1 createUser: false"`

the problem is based on that output line 147 should not execute at all, what is going on here?

```
(1 && false) == false
```

no?

I almost punched my computer last night. Just thought you might want to know.

The real problem is that if this code executes it basically adds an anonymous user to my user table, bad juju.

Comment: I believe there is best effort put into this by one of Cake's best programmers. However, I had similar issues which caused me to give up on using this plugin. GOOD LUCK!

Comment: In theory after looking at the code I could probably delete the block, but it feels like I am just being retarded somehow, and hope someone can point out my lameness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so bottom line, var_dump() in php saves lives. Failure on my part, my false was accidentally a string thank you aptana auto quotes.